# How to shift text below the circle using given XML code?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I am using below `XML` code with card and `RecyclerView` but I am getting the text inside the card and upper side But I would like to see the text below the circle, what changes should I make in the following XML code?

Reference image consists with current and desire output image as [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--
    grid items for RecyclerView
    -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ABCD"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `TextView` out of the `CardView` in order to have the `ImageView` fully occupy the entire area of the rounded `CardView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--
    grid items for RecyclerView
    -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="ABCD"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` can accept only 1 direct child so you need to wrap your views with another `ViewGroup` as following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--
    grid items for RecyclerView
    -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then you can adjust gravity of your view to your needs.

Comment: The text is shifted below but I would like to see it out from the circle, how could I get it?

Comment: @sanjaygupta Do you have a reference image how do you want it to look like?

Comment: I added the current desire output image, you may edit the code

Comment: @sanjaygupta for showing text below image circle you need `android:layout_below="@+id/image"` see my updated answer.

Comment: with this code I not able to see the text, the code is not working for desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myCardView"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="ABCD"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```